# What is the maximal possible 'non-empty' K-Core of a Graph G

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

Since any graph can be extracted to find K-Core easily, since finding K-Core is Pronominal problem, what is the maximal  possible 'non-empty' K-Core of a Graph G.
Is it k+1 ? or what exactly ?